# understanding Cruise Control .NET continuous integration

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I want to run a task/build after file change in my repository. 
when I configure the "Interval trigger": buildCondition="IfModificationExists",
the task doesn't execute although I changed a file and made a Commit..
the log writes:  No modifications detected.
how can I run the task just after file change?
thanks,
yehi

Comment: have you got a source control block in there?

Comment: here is my ccnet.config: <cruisecontrol>
    <project>
        <name>SimpleExample</name>  
 <triggers>
     <intervalTrigger initialSeconds="0"/> 
    </triggers>
 <sourcecontrol type="hg">
  <repo>http://localhost:8000</repo>
  <workingDirectory>c:\mercuRepo</workingDirectory>
 </sourcecontrol>
   <workingDirectory>C:\work  
   </workingDirectory>  
   <artifactDirectory>C:\work\project1CCnetArtifacts  
 </artifactDirectory>  
 <tasks>
     <exec>
  <executable>c:\calc.bat</executable>
     </exec>
 </tasks>
    </project>
</cruisecontrol>

Comment: soory for the mess. without any connection to the source control, when I make "force Build" the task happens but on "ifModificationExist" the task doesnt execute

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Mercurial Source Control as you can see here :
[CruiseControl.NET's Filtered Source Control Provider Not Detecting Modifications When Using Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498425/cruisecontrol-nets-filtered-source-control-provider-not-detecting-modifications)
http://groups.google.com.ag/group/ccnet-user/browse_thread/thread/23cc02e1258a63ec

Otherwise, your configuration seems correct, except you don't have login information in your source control block.

Answer (score 0):

personally id do the following:

```
<triggers>
<intervalTrigger initialSeconds="0" /> 1
</triggers>
<sourcecontrol type="<type here>">
```

as that polls the source control system and then only build if there are changes

please try that and see

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I tried, but it doesnt execute the task (like when I make force Build) although i can see it recognize my change- in the ccnet.log file. maybe task is different from build?